# Importing your own tensorflow model to react native

Tags: expo, tensorflow.js

I have a model which I trained and is stored as h5 file,
I used tensorflowJs converter to convert it to json file and weights.
I'm using expo, and I want to load that model, I understand that bundleResourceIO  doesn't work with exp and I'm suppose to load it from a webserver,
but I cannot find any tutorial or guide, is that even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [bundleResourceIO](https://js.tensorflow.org/api_react_native/0.3.0/#bundleResourceIO).

If you have multiple bin files then reconvert it again and set `--weight_shard_size_bytes 60000000` this sets the maximum size of the `weight_shard_size_bytes` file to 60Mb.

```
import {bundleResourceIO} from "@tensorflow/tfjs-react-native";


 //Loading model from models folder
  const modelJSON = require("../model/model.json");
  const modelWeights = require("../model/group1-shard1of1.bin");


// Load the model from the models folder
  const loadModel = async () => {
    const model = await tf
      .loadLayersModel(bundleResourceIO(modelJSON, modelWeights))
      .catch(e => console.log(e));
    console.log("Model loaded!");
    return model;
  };
```

Dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.12.0",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.10",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.7.3",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.9.0",
    "@tensorflow-models/blazeface": "^0.0.5",
    "@tensorflow/tfjs": "^2.0.0",
    "@tensorflow/tfjs-backend-webgl": "2.0.0",
    "@tensorflow/tfjs-converter": "^1.5.2",
    "@tensorflow/tfjs-core": "2.0.0",
    "@tensorflow/tfjs-react-native": "^0.3.0",
    "expo": "~38.0.8",
    "expo-camera": "~8.3.1",
    "expo-gl": "^8.4.0",
    "expo-gl-cpp": "~8.3.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "^1.0.2",
    "jpeg-js": "^0.4.2",
    "react": "~16.11.0",
    "react-dom": "~16.11.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-38.0.2.tar.gz",
    "react-native-canvas": "^0.1.37",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.16.6",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.6.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.9.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "~3.0.7",
    "react-native-screens": "~2.9.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.11.7"
  },
```

Comment: That's exactly what I did, and my expo crashes, and in the tensorflowjs official docs it said that it's not supported in expo apps https://js.tensorflow.org/api_react_native/0.3.0/  This IOHandler is not compatible with managed expo apps.

Comment: Hmm this is strange cause I just recently did a project using managed expo project. Could you try using the dependencies I am using? I will add it to the answer.

Comment: you know what, I tried again and it did not crash, but I get this message :" Unknown regularizer: L2. This may be due to one of the following reasons:
1. The regularizer is defined in Python, in which case it needs to be ported to TensorFlow.js or your JavaScript code.
2. The custom regularizer is defined in JavaScript, but is not registered properly with tf.serialization.registerClass()." do you know what this is?

Comment: nvm found the solution ,model loaded, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64063914/unknown-regularizer-l2-in-tensorflowjs

Answer (score -1):

I have resolved the issue by adding a metro.config.js file.
Add the follow code into the file so that it is able to read the bin file.

```
const { getDefaultConfig } = require('metro-config');
module.exports = (async () => {
  const defaultConfig = await getDefaultConfig();
  const { assetExts } = defaultConfig.resolver;
  return {
    resolver: {
      // Add bin to assetExts
      assetExts: [...assetExts, 'bin'],
    }
  };
})();
```

If you need a video guide watch this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pC7mCEHiYQw